# Magento 2 : Can I create a contact-us page or it should be by default?

Tags: magento2, contact-us

Can I create a contact-us page or it should be by default ?

If it should be by default, then why there is no admin?

can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, contact us functionality comes with default in Magento 2 functionality. You can find contact module on following path

```
<magento root>/vendor/magento/module-contact
```

Please let me know if you have any more question.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2, by default, provides the contact functionality, but it is limited to email only.

It does not provide the feature to save the contact requests in the database and manage these requests later from the admin panel.

If you want such a feature, you can create a custom table to save the data and write a **plugin/observer** on contact form submission.

Then you can create a custom grid to manage those requests from the admin panel.